# **EMERGE** (Java) Hashmap single key multi values, locate key in multi values Node

Tags: java, data-structures

The code below just to demonstrate an example of my code.

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> studentID = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    //studentID.put("P01", "P06" + "P07");
    studentID.put("P02", "P08" + "P09");
    studentID.put("P03", "P10");
    studentID.put("P04", "P11");
    studentID.put("P05", "P12");
    System.out.println(studentID.containsValue(P06));
```

So what I am struggling here is when there are multiple values in hashmap, Java will not be able to put up individual value as human do, for instance, System.out.println(studentID.containsValue(P06));, I am trying to locate P06 only but the program will display false as in it cannot pick up multiple values, in fact, it merged multiple values into one. Does anyone knows any solutions the I can search a single value when that value is based in a multi-values hashmap, and also but break when comes to using a key to search and allocate all values in the line, thank you.

Comment: What you need is a `Map<String, List<String>>`.  Or `ListMultimap` from a library like Guava.

Comment: emerge? did you mean *emergency*? HashMap doesn't merge values with equal keys, it replaces the earlier one by the latter. Mr. Wasserman mentioned alternatives. `"P08" + "P09"` btw is a string operation that concatenates the two strings to the string `"P08P09"`, maybe you interpreted this as a "merge". It is the same as if you'd write `"P08".concat("P09")`, minus a bit syntax sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the stream API.

```
boolean found = studentID.values().stream().
                anyMatch(value -> value.contains("P06"));
System.out.println(found);
```